# Search an attribute inside a Vector on Java

Tags: java, search, vector, iterator

I've a `Vector` of objects, and have to search inside for a random attribute of those objects (For example, a `Plane` class, a `Vector` containing `Plane`; and I've to search sometimes for `destination`, and others to `pilotName`).

I know I can traverse the `Vector` using an `Iterator`, but I've got stuck at how do I change the comparison made between a String and the attribute on the object. I thought of using `switch`, but a another opinion would be cool.

---

**Update 1:**

The code I've written is something like this (Java n00b alert!):

```
public int search(String whatSearch, String query){  
    int place = -1;  
    boolean found = false;  
    for ( Iterator<Plane> iteraPlane = this.planes.iterator(); iteraPlane.hasNext() && found == false; ) {  
        Plane temp = (Plane) iteraPlane.next();  
        /* Here is where I have to search for one of many attributes (delimited by whatSearch */ 
    }  
return place;  
}
```

Seems I've to stick to linear search (and that's a price I've able to pay). Anyway, I was thinking if Java had something like *variable variable name* (ouch!)

Comment: can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I think the key word here is *random* attribute. I've posted an answer below because I think you're asking about implementing an algorithm which searches for something where you don't know what is being searched *for* at the point of coding the algorithm. If you aren't asking this then I suggest you refine your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your problem is that you want to have a method that searches for a result based on *some property* of the collection type. Java is weak on this because it is best expressed in a language which has closures. What you need is something like:

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    public boolean evaluate(T t);
}
```

And then your search method looks like:

```
public static <T> T findFirst(List<T> l, Predicate<T> p) { //use List, not Vector
    for (T t : l) { if (p.evaluate(t)) return t; }
    return null;
}
```

Then anyone can use this *general-purpose* search method. For example, to search for an number in a vector of `Integer`s:

```
List<Integer> is = ...
findFirst(is, new Predicate<Integer> {
    public boolean evaluate(Integer i) { return i % 2 == 0; }
});
```

But you could implement the predicate in any way you want; for any arbitrary search

Comment: I agree, a Predicate seems ideally suited to this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collections.binarySearch` and provide a `Comparator`.

EDIT: This assumes that the `Vector` is sorted. Otherwise, one has to do a linear search.

Comment: note that for this the Vector needs to be sorted using the Compartor

Comment: The question is about searching for a *random* attribute so a search that pre-supposes a collection is sorted according to that attribute is pretty useless, isn't it? That would mean is wasn't very random

Comment: But I'd need to sort every time I search for a single attribute

Answer (score 0):

the `equals()` method is the best option.  For these iterations you could do something like this:

```
for (Plane plane: planes) {
   if ("JFK".equals(plane.getDestination())) {
      // do your work in here;
   }
}
```

or you could override the `equals()` method within `Plane` to see if the String passed in matches your destination (or pilot).  this will allow you to use the [`indexOf(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) and [`indexOf(Object, index)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object,%20int)) methods on `Vector` to return you the index(es) of the object(s).  Once you have that, you could use `Vector.get(index)` to return to Object for you.

in `Plane.java`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o.equals(getDestination()) ||
           o.equals(getPilot()) ||
           super.equals(o);    

}
```

there is more work to be done with this option, as you will need to override `hashCode()` as well ([see documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: Strictly speaking, if he doesn't put this objects in hashing containers, he doesn't need to worry about hashCode(). But it's good to do it correctly from the start.

Comment: i agree, it is better to cover your bases up front.

Answer (score 0):

See @oxbow_lakes above -- I think what you want isn't to pass a `String` as `whatSearch`, it's to pass a little snippet of code that knows how to get the property you're interested in. For a less general version:

```
public static interface PlaneMatcher {
    boolean matches(Plane plane, String query);
}


public int search(PlaneMatcher matcher, String query){  
    int place = -1;  
    boolean found = false;  
    for ( Iterator<Plane> iteraPlane = this.planes.iterator(); iteraPlane.hasNext() && found == false; ) {  
        Plane temp = (Plane) iteraPlane.next();  
        if (matcher.matches(temp, query) {
            found = true;
        }
        place++;
    }  
    return place;  
}

...
// example

int pilotNameIndex = search(new PlaneMatcher() {
        boolean matches(Plane plane, String query) {
            // note: assumes query non-null; you probably want to check that earlier
            return query.equals(plane.getPilotName());
        }
    }, "Orville Wright");
```

(By the way, if it's the index you're interested in rather than the `Plane` itself, I wouldn't bother with an `Iterator` -- just use an old-fashioned `for (int i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++)` loop, and when you have a match, `return i`.)

Now, the tricky bit here is if what you have to search for is really identified by arbitrary strings at run-time. If that's the case, I can suggest two alternatives:

1. Don't store these values as object fields -- `plane.pilotName`, `plane.destination` -- at all. Just have a `Map<String, String>` (or better yet, a `Map<Field, String>` where `Field` is an `Enum` of all the valid fields) called something like `plane.metadata`.
2. Store them as object fields, but prepopulate a map from the field names to `PlaneMatcher` instances as described above.

For instance:

```
private static final Map<String, PlaneMatcher> MATCHERS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, PlaneMatcher>() {{
    put("pilotName", new PlaneMatcher() {
        boolean matches(Plane plane, String query) {
            return query.equals(plane.getPilotName());
        });
    ...
    put("destination", new PlaneMatcher() {
        boolean matches(Plane plane, String query) {
            return query.equals(plane.getDestination());
        });
}}

...

public int search(String whatSearch, String query){  
    PlaneMatcher matcher = MATCHERS.get(whatSearch);
    int place = -1;  
    boolean found = false;  
    for ( Iterator<Plane> iteraPlane = this.planes.iterator(); iteraPlane.hasNext() && found == false; ) {  
        Plane temp = (Plane) iteraPlane.next();  
        if (matcher.matches(temp, query) {
            found = true;
        }
        place++;
    }  
    return place;  
}
```

Oh, and you might be tempted to use reflection. Don't. :)

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to pass a comparison function to your search routine. Or, if you need more speed, use generics.

Comment: "if you need more speed, use generics"? What on earth are you on about?

Comment: Maybe speed at which the programmer can type the program?